# Jquery: How to select only within a selection?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
var parent = $("#jcontent");
var button1 = parent(".button1")
```

How to select `.button1` knowing it is inside the parent while not reusing `#jcontent`?

I need to do this because I only want to pass the parent as parameter and to be able to cache it which is faster.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Another alternative

```
var parent = $("#jcontent"); 
var button1 = $(".button1", parent) ;
```

Comment: i like this ;) anyway both are great! I wish I could accept 2 answers xD thanks!

Comment: @JasperMogg The way I see it, this 'works', because this is the way the jQuery API is defined :). The second parameter of the selector expression (the JavaScript variable 'parent' holding a jQuery type value) indicates the scope within which the first parameter (the selector ".button1") is applied. If you leave out the second parameter, as is mostly done, then the default whole document is assumed as the scope to apply the selector.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Can you please elaborate? I am not clear about your question.

Comment: can you give link to jquery docs where it describes this behavior

Comment: Check https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1 . Look at the description of the context parameter.

Answer (score 16):

```
var button1 = parent.find(".button1");
```