# Why does this jQuery selector work? What is it based on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465278/jquery-how-to-select-only-within-a-selection-see-code-example-if-not-clear), the following code is used -

```
var parent = $("#jcontent"); 
var button1 = $(".button1", parent) ;
```

to select a button of class `button1` within the parent of id `jcontent`.

Why does this work? How does passing a jQuery object as a parameter to a jQuery selector tell it to select within that object? Can someone link to the docs which explain this function?

Comment: `$(".button1", parent)` is effectively the same thing as `parent.find('.button1')`.

Comment: I swear you're following me :-p Keep it up haha!

Comment: I like jQuery Mobile questions because answers for them can easily deviate away from standard JS answers.

Comment: I like them because they're pretty much the only ones I know anything about :-D What do you mean though? The deviation makes them more interesting, or you want to rein them back in to standard JS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the `context` parameter for the [core method call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1).

The parameter is described as:

> A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

And then there's a section labelled "Selector Context," which starts with:

> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function.

Answer (score 5):

The second parameter is the selector context: the DOM element, document, or jQuery object inside which the selector is matched. In the absence of this parameter, document root is assumed.

The following statement:

```
var button1 = $(".button1", parent); // parent = $("#jcontent")
```

is same as writing **:

```
var button1 = parent.find(".button1"); // parent = $("#jcontent")
```

and (in this case) produces results identical to this:

```
var button1 = $("#jcontent .button1");
```

** as mentioned [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span').