# Can I access the shadow DOM using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, polymer, shadow-dom

I defined a component with polymer like this:

```
<polymer-element name="my-component">
  <template>
    <div id='test'>CONTENT</div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Now I want to access the shadow dom, for example: to get the content of div id='test'

```
var x = $("div#test").html();
```

The given code doesn't work.
Can I access the shadow dom with jquery?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, not outside of the Polymer element.

After reading up on Polymer, it looks like you can only have access to the shadow-DOM of Polymer elements in scripts within the Polymer element. The Polymer docs on [Automatic node finding](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding) say:

> Every node in a component’s shadow DOM that is tagged with an id attribute is automatically referenced in the component’s this.$ hash.

This means you can add a `<script>` tag as a sibling to `<template>` where `this.$.test` will be the element you want.

```
<polymer-element name="my-component">
  <template>
    <div id='test'>CONTENT</div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-component', {
        logNameValue: function () {
            console.log('polymer element', this.$.test);
            console.log('jQuery wrapper of polymer element', $(this.$.test));
        }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Nice answer for 0.5, but I am not sure if this is still how it''s done in 1.0.

Comment: My question was irrelevant to polymer, but I found this answer helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58417950/897326

Answer (score 11):

You can use `$('body /deep/ your-selector')` pattern to pierce through shadow DOM and get Jquery to work inside it.

**update**: So far I have only managed to make this work on chrome for desktop. I believe, other browsers do not support the /deep/ combinator.

**update 2**: `/deep/` combinator is deprecated and should not be used anymore. It is scheduled to be removed from Chrome.

Comment: @NickFlekerFelker Maybe this [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/) can help you. ;)

Comment: `/deep/` seems to have been deprecated: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120

Comment: You are right. It is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

Answer (score 6):

I'm able to access the shadowRoot elements in Chrome like so:

```
$("#idOfElementInShadowRoot", $("#idOfShadowRootElement").shadowRoot)
```

Got the idea from [Jquery: How to select only within a selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465278/jquery-how-to-select-only-within-a-selection)

Comment: You will need a `[0]` after `$("#idOfShadowRootElement")`, because `.shadowRoot` is on DOM objects but not on jQuery ones. So like this: `$("#idOfElementInShadowRoot", $("#idOfShadowRootElement")[0].shadowRoot)`

Comment: Have to be using the "open" mode of `attachShadow` for this to work. "closed" mode will give you null. Otherwise a great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think this works for me...

```
$('polymer-element::shadow #test')
```

Only tested it on chrome though

Comment: This is also deprecated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741722/whats-the-substitute-for-shadow-and-deep

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#example", this.shadowRoot).DataTable();
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

`$(element)[0].shadowRoot`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote simple helper in TypeScript to solve this problem:

```
class DomUtils {

    public static getShadowElementById(id: string):any {

        try {
            // Try to get it by simple id in case of browser doesn't support shadow DOM
            var element = $("#" + id);

            if (element.length <= 0) {
                // Support Chrome browser
                element = $("body /deep/ #" + id);
            }

            return element;

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error + ", while trying to get shadow element with id: " + id);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var element = DomUtils.getShadowElementById('mainContainer');
```

Tested on desktop Chrome, Internet Explorer, Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  shadowRoot: function() {
     return $(this.get(0).shadowRoot);
  },
});
```

and call:

```
$("my-element").shadowRoot());
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my simple function to change capcha in shadow-root

```html
const get_captcha = (CustomElement)=>{
 var src = `./app/create_captcha/${chance.natural()}`;
 var rootElement = $(CustomElement)[0].shadowRoot;
 var captchaElement = $(rootElement).find('#img_captcha');
 $(captchaElement).attr('src',src);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth tossing this into the list of answers since it's ultimately what I used.

```
// following line assumes shadow content has only one <body> tag... 
// ...otherwise filter by whatever makes sense for your code

var $shadowBody = $($("#shadow-root-elem")[0].shadowRoot.childNodes).filter("body");

// get the elem in the shadow content that I need/want

var $elemInShadowBody = $shadowBody.find(".selector.for.elem.in.shadow.body")
```